# DateTime.TryParseExact and different separators

Tags: .net

Is it possible to instruct DateTime.TryParseExact to accept multiple (**any**) sepatators (**specify separator placeholder instead of particular separator**)? For instance:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(performanceRow[5], "M/d/yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out startDate)
```

This works if date has '/' character as separator. However I've just received a file with '.' as separator, and parsing fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this variant of TryParseExact

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime%)
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

The second param is a string array which is defined as

> **formats**
>
> Type: System.String[]
>
> An array of allowable formats of s.

The description says: The format of the string representation must match **at least one of the specified formats exactly**.

Comment: But what if somebody will upload a file with another separator that is not listed in my format list? I support only M/d/yyyy, but separator character could be any character.

Comment: Ahh well that becomes a different problem - It is more like I have to parse some input, but I dont know the format of the input. Your program will have to retrict to a set of specified formats. Or, have the person sending the file also send the format within the file or through a separate field. Otherwise, you will never know how to parse at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass format in array like below,

```
string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
               "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
               "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
```

pass this format as second parameter in TryParseExact method.

Answer (score 1):

I just got done creating this list of formats to make my validation as inclusive as possible of typical UK date formats without introducing ambiguity. Hopefully this is helpful to someone.

```
{
    // slash separator:
    "d/M/y",        //no leading 0s
    "dd/M/y",       //leading 0 in date
    "d/MM/y",       //leading 0 in month
    "dd/MM/y",      //leading 0 in date & month
    "d/M/yyyy",     //leading 0 in year
    "dd/M/yyyy",    //leading 0 in date & year
    "d/M/yyyy",     //leading 0 in date, month & year
    // dash separator:
    "d-M-y",        //no leading 0s
    "dd-M-y",       //leading 0 in date
    "d-MM-y",       //leading 0 in month
    "dd-MM-y",      //leading 0 in date & month
    "d-M-yyyy",     //leading 0 in year
    "dd-M-yyyy",    //leading 0 in date & year
    "d-M-yyyy",     //leading 0 in date, month & year
    // dot separator:
    "d.M.y",        //no leading 0s
    "dd.M.y",       //leading 0 in date
    "d.MM.y",       //leading 0 in month
    "dd.MM.y",      //leading 0 in date & month
    "d.M.yyyy",     //leading 0 in year
    "dd.M.yyyy",    //leading 0 in date & year
    "d.M.yyyy",     //leading 0 in date, month & year
}
```